# Classify Different Video Frames by the Effect

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, machine-learning, classification, video-processing

I'm trying to do shot boundary detection using SVM's.

I'm differentiating between 3 shots, cut, fade and dissolve + (normal frames).

I had used two features, shannon's entropy and variance, it gave me 40/635 boundary frames correctly predicted. That is poor accuracy.

What features can I use to improve this?

Training videos: 2 videos from TRECVID (~50000 frames)
Test Videos: 1 Video TRECVID (~13000 frames)

EDIT:

So one must be careful in choosing features.

So I fixed a problem that was occuring, if anyone comes across this post, then the above features are okay and will give you pretty good results for CUT detection.

Comment: you might need to work on your feature vectors. I'm pretty sure you can do better than those two single numbers.

Comment: Check my edit @MarcusMüller, Can you suggest some features or a feature selection method in OpenCV? Adaboost is common but i think get_weak_features is decrepated in newer versions

Comment: hm, those are still onedimensional measures for the difference between two frames, right?

Comment: Yes, also hold on let me get some values for you, check edit again for values

Comment: Also a doubt I have been having is should I use longer features (~100 sized feat vector), also check my edit again I added another query

Comment: Can you provide a couple of example images to know what is this boundary frames you are talking about. (answering because i cannot comment yet)

Comment: Here is an example, not my work but it gives you the idea http://chenlab.ece.cornell.edu/projects/Video2Clips/images/video2clips.png

Different kinds of shots described

Comment: Adding motion feature between consecutive frames could provide you better results

Comment: motion feature? Please elaborate